CUPS - lp doesn't print when given more than one file
I have a Brother HLL2390DW all in one printer connected by USB to my Kubuntu 22.04 notebook using brother-HLL2390DW-cups-en.ppd from their website.
If I issue an lp file1.pdf it works fine, but if I issue an lp file1.pdf file2.pdf, the printer wakes up, but doesn't print anything.
/var/log/cups/error_log shows:
W [23/Nov/2024:00:00:28 -0500] Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS. See https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/103
W [23/Nov/2024:02:05:49 -0500] Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS. See https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/103
W [23/Nov/2024:05:17:30 -0500] Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS. See https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/103
E [23/Nov/2024:18:22:58 -0500] [Job 66] Unable to add document to print job.
E [23/Nov/2024:18:46:36 -0500] [Job 67] Unable to add document to print job.
E [23/Nov/2024:18:59:48 -0500] [Job 69] Print job canceled at printer.
W [23/Nov/2024:18:59:48 -0500] [Job 69] Backend returned status 5 (cancel job)
E [23/Nov/2024:19:04:23 -0500] [Job 70] Unable to add document to print job.
E [23/Nov/2024:19:04:31 -0500] [Job 70] Print job canceled at printer.
W [23/Nov/2024:19:04:31 -0500] [Job 70] Backend returned status 5 (cancel job)

$ lpstat -a
Brother_HL_L2390DW_USB not accepting requests since Sat 23 Nov 2024 05:36:03 PM EST -
        Rejecting Jobs
BrotherHLL2390D not accepting requests since Sat 02 Nov 2024 08:10:19 PM EDT -
        Rejecting Jobs
HLL2390DW accepting requests since Sat 23 Nov 2024 07:12:01 PM EST

The other two instances were from previous attempts to hook up the printer as a networked printer using an Ethernet to USB print server adapter, etc. (I'll ask a separate question about that once this works.) I manually disabled them.

Not sure what I did, but reinstalling the printer and choosing the driver (not driverless) version of the printer in CUPS seems to have fixed it.
The driver was obtained manually from their website and had to be manually entered in CUPS (localhost:631/) because it wasn't a preloaded choice.
